# How to add background image to my tab panel items?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

This is my code.I config tab panel in cofig session.i took tow items 1) Property Condition Report 
2) Inspection Report i want add background image to these tab panel items.

```
 config: {
         style: 'background-color: white;border:0;width:100%',
         flex: 1,
         tabBar: {
             layout: {
               pack: 'center',
               align: 'center',
           }
       },
            items: [{
                title: 'Property Condition Report',
                xtype: 'propertyConditionReport'

            },{
                title: 'Inspection Report',
                xtype: 'inspectionReport'
            }, ],


        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a css class to each item and then apply some styles.
[Here](http://www.sencha.com/blog/an-introduction-to-theming-sencha-touch) a tutorial about theming.

```
items: [{
 title: 'Property Condition Report',
 xtype: 'propertyConditionReport',
 cls:'propertyConditionReport' // css class
},{
 title: 'Inspection Report',
 xtype: 'inspectionReport',
 cls: 'inspectionReport' // css class
}]
```